# How to write query with outer joins and multiple OR criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In this query we perform outer joins from a large table `release` to two tables `release_event` and `release_barcode`. These must be outer joins, because in the results we want to return releases which don't have entries in either table:

```
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r, release_event.cat, release_barcode.barcode
FROM   release r 
    left join release_event event ON r.source_uri = event.source_uri 
    left join release_barcode barcode ON r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri 
WHERE  ( event.cat IN ( '3145422912' ) AND event.label_name = 'UTV Records' ) 
    OR barcode.barcode IN ( '731454229128' )
```

When analysed, this performs a sequential scan on the `release` table:

```
|   ->  Sort  (cost=2169219.61..2169219.65 rows=13 width=66)                                                                                                                  |
|         Sort Key: r.source_uri                                                                                                                                              |
|         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=721970.94..2169219.37 rows=13 width=66)                                                                                                   |
|               Hash Cond: ((r.source_uri)::text = (barcode.source_uri)::text)                                                                                                |
|               Filter: ((((event.cat)::text = '3145422912'::text) AND ((event.label_name)::text = 'UTV Records'::text)) OR ((barcode.barcode)::text = '731454229128'::text)) |
|               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=589927.01..1568193.22 rows=11405330 width=88)                                                                                      |
|                     Hash Cond: ((event.source_uri)::text = (r.source_uri)::text)                                                                                            |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on release_event event  (cost=0.00..283078.30 rows=11405330 width=65)                                                                      |
|                     ->  Hash  (cost=324393.56..324393.56 rows=10963956 width=66)                                                                                            |
|                           ->  Seq Scan on release r  (cost=0.00..324393.56 rows=10963956 width=66)                                                                          |
|               ->  Hash  (cost=63125.97..63125.97 rows=2965197 width=60)                                                                                                     |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on release_barcode barcode  (cost=0.00..63125.97 rows=2965197 width=6
```

If I have just one of the above criteria, the query planner (Postgresql) understands this, using the indexes to limit results from `release`:

```
|   ->  Sort  (cost=42.26..42.27 rows=3 width=66)                                                                               |
|         Sort Key: r.source_uri                                                                                                |
|         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..42.24 rows=3 width=66)                                                                   |
|               ->  Index Scan using release_barcode_barcode_idx on release_barcode barcode  (cost=0.43..16.47 rows=3 width=47) |
|                     Index Cond: ((barcode)::text = '731454229128'::text)                                                      |
|               ->  Index Scan using release_pkey on release r  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=66)                               |
|                     Index Cond: ((source_uri)::text = (barcode.source_uri)::text)
```

How can I rewrite queries with outer joins and multiple OR'd criteria to first limit the joined tables and only lookup the `release` table for any of those rows that match?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `where` clause on the outer joined tables turns your outer joins into inner joins

Comment: only almost, there's an OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try writing this using `exists`:

```
SELECT r.source_uri as su_on_r, r.title as t_on_r
FROM release r 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM release_event re
              WHERE r.source_uri = re.source_uri AND
                    re.cat IN ( '3145422912' ) AND re.label_name = 'UTV Records'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM release_barcode rb 
              WHERE r.source_uri = rb.source_uri AND
                    rb.barcode IN ( '731454229128' ) 
             );
```

For these queries, I would recommend indexes on `release_event(source_uri, cat, label_name)` and `release_barcode(source_uri, barcode)`.

You can also phrase the query using `union` (to remove duplicates):

```
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r
FROM release r JOIN
     release_event event
     ON r.source_uri = event.source_uri 
WHERE  event.cat IN ( '3145422912' ) AND event.label_name = 'UTV Records' 
UNION
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r
FROM release r JOIN
     release_barcode
     ON r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri 
WHERE barcode.barcode IN ( '731454229128' )  ;
```

Comment: I should say, I still need data from the `release_event` and `release_barcode` tables, so they need to be joined... does this affect that? Sorry, I was making the select statement simple in the example, will edit.

Comment: @DanGravell . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have another question, then ask as *another* question.  If you edit this question, you will invalidate this answer which could draw downvotes.  In the meantime, I would recommend that you try these approaches to see if the performance improves.

Comment: When I run the `exists` solution, I still get a seq scan on the `release` table.

Comment: @DanGravell . . . That is interesting -- such are the curiosities of SQL optimizers.

Answer (score 2):

Filter before joining:

```
select 
    source_uri as su_on_r, 
    r.title as t_on_r, 
    event.cat, 
    barcode.barcode
from  
    release r 
    left join (
        select *
        from release_event
        where cat in ('3145422912') and label_name = 'utv records'
    ) event using (source_uri)
    left join (
        select *
        from release_barcode 
        where barcode in ('731454229128') 
    ) barcode using (source_uri)
```

Comment: I still get a seq scan on the release table when I do this. The estimated cost is marginally smaller.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but what if you moved your `where` conditions inside the left join and then tested to see if either/or record was successful in the join:

```
SELECT
  r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r, release_event.cat, release_barcode.barcode
FROM
  release r 
  left join release_event event ON
    r.source_uri = event.source_uri  and
    event.cat IN ( '3145422912' ) AND 
    event.label_name = 'UTV Records'
  left join release_barcode barcode ON 
     r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri and
     barcode.barcode IN ( '731454229128' ) 
WHERE
  event.source_uri is not null or
  barcode.source_uri is not null
```

@a_horse_with_no_name made a comment about how your construct actually becomes an inner join, and I think this would overcome that.  Whether it gets the results (and performance you seek), I'm not certain.

Comment: This appears to still do a seq scan on the `release` table, although the overall estimated cost of the query is about 1/4 that of the original query.